# Magento 2 Avalara Tax on shipping?

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento2.3, tax

We installed Avalara Tax module in magento 2.2.4 CE and configured.
We would like to setup calculating Avalara tax on shipping and handling.

I am trying to configure from magento admin end but showing note mentioned on the screen shot below

https://prnt.sc/mwnhlt

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Important note of `AvaTax` it may answer your query

> Important Notes

- Magento discounts are subtracted from the price before the total
  amount is sent to AvaTax to retrieve tax information. AvaTax is not
  sent any information about the discount amount, as the AvaTax 15 API
  does not support itemized discounting the way Magento does.
- The extension has been tested in multiple currencies.
- Transaction IDs in AvaTax are mapped to Magento's invoice and credit
  memo numbers.
- Default tax reporting in Magento displays tax collected by each tax
  rule you created in the system. However, when using AvaTax, Magento
  tax rules are not used; instead, tax rules and calculations are
  configured within AvaTax. Because of this, Magento's tax report will
  (correctly) show that there are no Magento tax rules collecting tax.
  A full tax report suite is available within your AvaTax dashboard.
- If you've customized checkout at all, it is your responsibility to
  confirm the continued functionality of Address Validation.
- AvaTax will only accept an invoice ID and credit memo ID once per
  store. Thus if you're testing in environments that are capable of
  duplicating those values, be careful to increment those values in
  Magento or create new test stores in AvaTax.
- Every time you save a customer in Magento, Magento will reach out and
  attempt to update that customer's data in AvaTax. If the customer
  doesn't exist, the module just ignores the error and will try again
  the next time you save the customer in Magento. This happens on
  customer save within the admin, as well as on the front end.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Hasham for providing valuable information. but i m unable to find out the setting at avalara portal to configure the tax on shipping and handling

Comment: let me explain you with screenshots https://prnt.sc/mx6t9v  https://prnt.sc/mx6u35 at magento front end it should display tax as 34.69 instead of 33.66 i hope now you understood. could u please review and advise now

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Hasham client has been fixed with the configuration at avalara dashboard and i am not sure how they configured. thanks once again

Comment: No problem @Nagaraju if my answer is helpful for you then please mark my answer correct so it helps other readers as well. Keep coding :) thanks